# Which way to lean when driving a gokart?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Given a car that has two lines of wheels, the center of gravity at constant height above the ground, constant turn angle and given surface and wheel material.

What is the maximum speed the car can drive without the wheels sliding given the position of center of gravity (leaning in, leaning out or central)?

Comment: The problem really depends on the non-linearity of pneumatic tires and suspension linkages. A general answer would involve deciding which configuration resulted in more even radial forces on the tires. a 50/50 dynamic weight distribution left to right is optimal.

Comment: A couple of articles explaining "dynamic weight" : http://www.autospies.com/news/Dynamic-weight-distribution-and-transfer-47066/  ,   http://oppositelock.jalopnik.com/dynamic-weight-distribution-and-transfer-179982356

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct approach in a go-kart is leaning outwards.
I think this is useful because go-karts do not have a differential between the left and right wheels. So the wheels are forced to turn at the same rate. Because the turn radius is not the same for the inner and outer wheels there must be some slip. Leaning outwards facilitates this without the go-kart loosing grip.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! This answer would be better if accompanied by references or the math to back it up.